# Edit text when I open a window

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, qlineedit

I'm working with PYQt5 and Python. Whenever I open a new window and that window has a lineEdit, I have to clic in the lineEdit in order to write any text. Is there a way in which I can start writing the text in the lineEdit just the moment I open the window without, first, having to clic on it?

Thanks!

Edit. Here is the code I've been using

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QThread, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

from PyQt5.uic import loadUi

class VentanaInicio(QMainWindow):
    path = "null"
    def __init__(self):
        super(VentanaInicio,self).__init__()
        loadUi('D:\Matt\Combi\Archivo.ui',self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.conectar)

    # Abrir Ventana Video
    def conectar(self):
        self.crear_carpeta()
        iniciar = VentanaVideo()
        iniciar.exec_()
    # Salir
    def conectar1(self):
        self.close()

    def crear_carpeta(self):
        VentanaInicio.path = str(self.lineEdit.text())
        if not self.lineEdit.text():
            VentanaInicio.path = "null"

        try:
            os.mkdir(VentanaInicio.path)
            print("Carpeta Creada")
        except FileExistsError:
            print("Carpeta Existe")

        return VentanaInicio.path
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Also, see [`setFocus()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFocus-1).

Comment: I made an edit and copied the the code I've been using. Where should I add the setFocus()?

Comment: Thanks to your suggestion I made it work. I will mark this as solved. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. BTW, for future reference, allow me a suggestion: you can obviously write *your own* code as you like, but the common language of programming is English, and code readability is an extremely important matter. When sharing code with others (not only here, but also on public repositories) this is an aspect that *must* be kept in mind: most developers are *not* native English speakers, but having function/variable/class names in *that* common language dramatically improves readability (and, along with it, debugging and people being able to help you much more easily).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to musicamante the question was solved. I added the setFocus() like this.

```
    def __init__(self):
        super(VentanaInicio,self).__init__()
        loadUi('D:\Matt\Combi\Archivo.ui',self)
        self.lineEdit.setFocus(True)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.conectar)
```